# Updating redux state onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component that displays data from the state. I'm using redux for state. I want to be able to click a button and filter the state. But I'm stuck on dispatching the action from the button.

Right now I have a button that is supposed to dispatch the action but it's not being called. I'm not sure if the mapsToDispatchProps is wrong or it's something else.

Here is the actions

```
import { GET_POLLS, SHOW_APPROVAL } from './types';


const URL = 'https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/polls/polls.json';

export const getPolls = () => dispatch => {

    return fetch(URL)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(polls => {
            dispatch({ type: GET_POLLS, payload: polls })
        })


}

export const getApproval = () => ({ type: SHOW_APPROVAL })
```

reducer

```
import {
    GET_POLLS,
    SHOW_APPROVAL
} from '../actions/types';



const pollReducer = (state = [], { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case GET_POLLS:
            return payload
        case SHOW_APPROVAL:
            return (payload.type === "trump-approval")
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default pollReducer;
```

types

```
export const GET_POLLS = 'GET_POLLS';
export const POLLS_LOADING = 'POLLS_LOADING';
export const SHOW_ALL = 'SHOW_ALL';
export const SHOW_APPROVAL = 'SHOW_APPROVAL';
```

list that displays data

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { PollCard } from '../Components/PollCard'
// import FilterLink from './FilterLink'
import * as moment from 'moment';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getPolls, getApproval } from '../actions/index';

class PollList extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getPolls();
    }



    render() {


        console.log("rendering list")
        const { polls } = this.props

        const range = 30
        var dateRange = moment().subtract(range, 'days').calendar();
        var filteredPolls = polls.filter(e => Date.parse(e.endDate) >= Date.parse(dateRange)).reverse()



        return (

            <React.Fragment>
                <button onClick={getApproval}>
                    Get Approval

                </button>
                {console.log("get approval", getApproval)}


                {
                    filteredPolls && filteredPolls.map((poll) => (
                        <div key={poll.id}>
                            <PollCard poll={poll} />

                            {/* {(poll.type)} */}

                        </div>
                    ))




                }
            </React.Fragment>

        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    polls: state.polls
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getApproval
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
    { getPolls, getApproval }
)(PollList);


// export default PollList;
```

Comment: hi! Just provided a solution to you, let me know if that helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mapDispatchToProps()` appears to be configured incorrectly. You need to define a `function` that returns an `object`, defining a key-value pair for each `action` you want to make available as a `prop` in your component.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
      getApproval: () => {
         dispatch(getApproval())
      },
      getPolls: () => {
         dispatch(getPolls())
      }
   }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProp)(PollList);
```

Now getPolls is available as prop and you can use it in `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPolls();
}
```

You should also create an onClick handler for your `getApproval` action

```
handleClick = () => {
   this.props.getApproval()
}
```

And then connect it to your onClick event-listener

```
<React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Get Approval
    </button>
    console.log("get approval", getApproval)}
    {
        filteredPolls && filteredPolls.map((poll) => (
           <div key={poll.id}>
              <PollCard poll={poll} />
                 {/* {(poll.type)} */}
           </div>
        ))
    }
</React.Fragment>
```

### Action File

```
export const getPolls = () => dispatch => {
      fetch(URL)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(polls => {
            dispatch({ type: GET_POLLS, payload: polls })
        })
        .catch(errors => {
            dispatch({ type: "GET_ERRORS", payload: errors.response.data })
        })
}
```

### Reducer

```
import {
    GET_POLLS,
    SHOW_APPROVAL
} from '../actions/types';

const pollReducer = (state = [], { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case GET_POLLS:
            return payload
        case SHOW_APPROVAL:
            return state.filter((poll) => {
                return poll.type === "trump-approval"
            })
        case "GET_ERRORS":
            return payload
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default pollReducer;
```

Comment: I get a red line under dispatch in mapDispatchToProps

Comment: @jhaywoo8 oh sorry I forgot to pass in dispatch as an argument. Can you try my updated solution now :)

Comment: now I get this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined"

Comment: @jhaywoo8 thats good. We're closing to deducing what's wrong. It looks like the action actually does get called now. Does your payload ( the data returned from the back end ) have a key called type? Are the polls an array or an object? It sounds like its an array.

Comment: get this error now with the new code: "Error: Given action "SHOW_APPROVAL", reducer "polls" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined."

Comment: @jhaywoo8 right, because in this line `(payload.type === "trump-approval")`. you arent returning anything, you are just making a comparison. Just try `return payload` instead, it should give you the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194401/discussion-between-jhaywoo8-and-christopher-ngo).

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the action function.

```js
// Either destructure it
const { polls, getApproval } = this.props;
<button onClick={getApproval}>
    Get Approval
</button>
// Or use this.props.function
<button onClick={this.props.getApproval}>
    Get Approval
</button>
```

```js
// You don't need this
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getApproval
};
// You don't need this

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {polls: state.polls};
};
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    // Doing this is easier, cleaner & faster
    { getPolls, getApproval }
)(PollList);
```

Here you are doing it correctly;

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPolls();
}
```

Comment: I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined"